# Convert script from jQuery to prototype or vanilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I am working with an API and their examples are dependent upon jQuery for manipulating the css selectors.  Can someone please show me how I could accomplish this with either the Prototype library or else vanilla javaScript?

```
  scrollEnd = function (element, dir, enable, init) {
    var el = jQuery(element);
    if (el.size()) {
      if (enable) {
        if (el.css('backgroundImage') == "none")
          el.css('backgroundImage', element.button);
      }
      else {
        element.button = el.css('backgroundImage');
        el.css('backgroundImage', "none");
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Is `element` always a DOM element, or can it be a selector string (or jQuery collection)? That matters a bit for both vanilla DOM (obviously) and for Prototype (since Prototype, unlike jQuery, treats lists of elements differently from how it treats a single element).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vanilla

```
scrollEnd = function (element, dir, enable, init) {
    if (enable) {
        if (!element.style.backgroundImage) {
            element.style.backgroundImage = element.button;
        } else {
            element.button = element.style.backgroundImage;
            delete element.style.backgroundImage;
        }
    }
};
```

I know of no DOMElement that has an attribute `size` AND `button` though .. what did I just write? :P

Comment: Thanks! No more errors but it still is not working.  I am working with the ATG recommendation engine.. here is a link (at the bottom is what you rewrote) http://recmanager.atg.com/api/renderer/scroller.html

Comment: Oh, then `el.size()` probably checks if the element actually exists. I'll ammend the code.

Comment: Hmm.. thanks again.. but no dice.. it just keeps on a scrolling

Comment: Ahh.. making my life harder than I need to.. there is no need for me to even to try and customize this.. I read the API again and figured it out.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: This function doesn't do anything with scrolling. It just swaps a background-image. I think you've got the wrong part of the script.

Comment: It does have to do with scrolling in that when it reaches the end of the items it makes the nav image disappear.. so it prevents scrolling.